# module 'networkx' has no attribute 'add_nodes_from'

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

I have a dictionary with author name strings as indexes and the number of publications as the associated value. When I try adding nodes to a new graph from it, I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'networkx' has no attribute 'add_nodes_from'
```

Here is a sample code:

```
import networkx as nx
auth_dict = {"albert": 1, "Barbie": 3, "Charlie": 8}
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G = nx.add_nodes_from(auth_dict)
```

Environment is pip managed python 3.7.2 with networkx 2.2, MacOS 10.13.6

This is the reference I tried to follow: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html#networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from

Thank you

Comment: you get a not defined error because add_nodes_form should be nx.add_nodes_form.

Comment: The documentation OP links for their networkx version says it's a method on `Graph`s, rather than a function on the module, so I think it should be `G.add_nodes_from`.

Comment: @TomAtix oh very sorry that was a typo but no even that does yield the error I was referring to.

Comment: @wbadart2 YES that was the problem! Thank you for clearing out my confusion.

Comment: @wbadart sorry, i didn't mean to 'steal' your answer, i hadn't seen your comment when typing my own answer :)

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `add_nodes_from` the wrong way. It is a method of the base  [`MultiGraph`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multigraph.html) class, and not an attribute of the `networkx` module itself. So the Syntax should be

```
G = nx.MultiGraph()
G.add_nodes_from(auth_dict)
```

(notice the dot instead of '=').

So i guess you're calling it as

```
G = nx.add_nodes_from(foo)
```

in your main code, which is, again, the wrong syntax - look [here](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9/reference/generated/networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from.html#networkx.Graph.add_nodes_from) or at the link you posted yourself for more info.

Comment: Yes that was the case as also pointed out kindly by @wbadart2 in a comment to my flawed code, Thanks!